# MagicalRecord throws relatedByAttribute error

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I have an strange error in my log and I am not sure what I  need to check.

> Invalid value for key 'relatedByAttribute' in 'WorkoutEntity' entity. Remove this key or add attribute

This is one place what I found where I use `relatedByAttribute` in `WorkoutEntity`

Do you have an idea what can I check as well to see issue.

[image: e]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I opened the .xcdatamodeld with an external editor, looked for the "relatedByAttribute" label and found that the label was "relatedByAttribute " instead (note the blank space). 
Removed the blank and worked since then.
I hope it's good for you! ;)

Comment: thanks for answer, checked but no spaces ( but thanks for suggestions!